# Strange behaviour of NSShadow for customized NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa

I subclass the NSWindow and use `[self setHasShadow:YES]` to set the shadow for window. But the shadow shows abnormally when:

Move the window a little out of the screen, then resize the window to a larger size, then when I drag back the whole window from outside the screen, I find that system does not draw shadow for those part covered by screen before.

[image]

*the right part without shadow was covered by screen before*

To get full shadow, I must resize the window again to let system redraw the shadow.

So is there a way to avoid this behaviour? Maybe it is more efficient to only the shadow for those parts in screen, but I hope it can redraw automatically when the whole window is in screen.

Comment: I tried `[self invalidateShadow]`, but not find a good place for it.

Comment: Have you tried calling `[window invalidateShadow]` in `windowDidMove:` handler?

Comment: Yes, I really tried it in `windowDidMove:`, but the problem is, when the window is moved out of screen, `[self invalidateShadow]` will be called, and system redraws the shadow, as a result, those parts will not have shadow, and once the window is moved back in screen, `[self invalidateShadow]` will be called again, then the shadow is full back. In the whole process, I can still see the change of shadow, not good enough.